# SVN tag not listed in tags directory

Tags: svn, tags

My SVN repository uses the recommended SVN directory structure (tags/, branches/...)

I noticed that `ls tags` is missing a particular tag.  However, when I `svn ls "^/tags"` I find the tag.  Why would these 2 commands yield different results?

TIA

Comment: Typo in question?  ls "^/tags wouldn't run because it is missing a quote.  And I think you meant "./tags" or something else.

Comment: @Jeanne - Yes, I fixed the missing quotation marks.  I got the "^/tags" syntax from stackoverflow and your suggested "./tags" does the same thing.